# How do I install npgsql in Debian?

Tags: debian, postgresql, .net

How to install `npgsql` to Debian? Google gives me only an articles how to install PostgreSQL.

Comment: Are you looking for PostgreSQL library package for mono?

Comment: I am looking for PostgreSQL .NET Core provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to solve my problem.

1. Install .NET Core SDK and use `dotnet add package`.
2. Publish app from
       Visual Studio or `dotnet publish`. In that case all dll will be in
       directory.